# <s:select> with dynamic list name

Tags: java, jsp, select, struts2, ognl

I want to iterate over a list of strings containing names for `<s:select>` list source, but the HTML output is not as expected : **it's the name of the list that is display, not the content**.

**My `Action` code:**

```
public class DescriptionTabArchiveAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<String> vegetables = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

    // contain "vegetables" and "devices".
    private List<String> selectList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Action("multipleSelect")
    public String multipleSelect() {
                vegetables.add("tomato");
                vegetables.add("potato");

                devices.add("mouse");
                devices.add("keyboard");

                selectList.add("vegetables");
                selectList.add("devices");

        return SUCCES;
    }

       // getters and setters
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<s:iterator value="selectList" var="listName">

    <s:select list="%{#listName}" />

    <!-- I tried with this line too : same behaviour. -->
    <%-- <s:select list="#listName" /> --%>
</s:iterator>
```

**What I get (html ouput):**

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="vegetables">vegetables</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="devices">devices</option>
</select>
```

**What I expect (html output):**

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="tomato">tomato</option>
    <option value="potato">potato</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="mouse">mouse</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
</select>
```

**My Question:**

How can I dynamically iterate over a list of string to have multiple `<s:select>` with different list source?

Comment: Try filling out the rest of the select attributes. [Select tag documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/select.html)

Comment: @Dan: I simplified the problem by deleting useless tags to keep focus on the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Map` instead of `List`

```
private Map<String, List<String>> selectMap = new HashMap<>();
//getter and setter here

@Action("multipleSelect")
public String multipleSelect() {
    vegetables.add("tomato");
    vegetables.add("potato");

    devices.add("mouse");
    devices.add("keyboard");

    selectMap.put("vegetables", vegetables);
    selectMap.put("devices", devices);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

modify iterator to use a map

```
<s:iterator value="selectMap">    
    <s:select list="%{value}" />
    ...
</s:iterator>
```